# Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C} - {0}$, such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} zf(z) = 1 = \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} f(z)$...

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C} - {0}$, such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} zf(z) = 1 = \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} f$, then prove that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ when $|z|>1$

I thought the best way to prove this would be to approach is by contradiction, supposing it was unbounded and trying to find inconsistency, however, I don't know how to link its unboundedness to the limit at infinity. I certainly have no idea how to link it to its limit at 0 as that doesn't seem related to the case we are handling when $|z|>1$.

I also encounter the following problem:

$|z f(z)| \leq |z||f(z)| \leq M|z|$

But I let $|z| \rightarrow 0$ on both sides then I end up with $0\geq 1$.

The final aim of this question is to see that the only $f$ that satisfies this is $f(z) = \frac{1+z}{z}$

Any help welcome :)

Comment: Is this the complete problem? Because I don't see why the assumption $\lim_{z\to0}z f(z)=1$ is necessary here

Comment: This is not the complete problem but I think I am okay with the rest

Comment: Well, if $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=1$ then there is some $K>0$ such that for all $z$ with $|z|>K$ we have $|f(z)-1|<1$, in particular $f$ is bounded for $|z|>K$.

Comment: How do I show that $K=1$

Comment: $K$ doesn't have to be $1$ but on the compact set $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid 1\leq|z|\leq K\}$ $f$ is bounded anyway.